# How to prove that a sequence is null?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How to prove that ${2\over n^2}$ is a null sequence?

Comment: Do you know how to prove $\frac{2}{n} \rightarrow 0, n \rightarrow \infty$? Or that $\left\{\frac{2}{n^2}\right\}$ is descending and bounded?

Answer (score 2):

You wish to show that for each $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a number $N=N(\epsilon) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n > N$, 
$$\left|\dfrac{2}{n^2}-0\right| = \left|\dfrac{2}{n^2}\right| < \epsilon$$
Working backwards, we obtain
$$n^2>\dfrac{2}{\epsilon}\implies \sqrt{n^2}=|n|=n>\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\epsilon}}$$
So, take $N$ to be 
$$N = \left\lceil\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\epsilon}}\ \right\rceil$$
where the ceiling function $\lceil \cdot \rceil$ is used.

> **Proof**. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Choose $N = \left\lceil\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\epsilon}}\ \right\rceil$. Then for all $n > N$,
>   $$\left|\dfrac{2}{n^2}-0\right|=\left|\dfrac{2}{n^2}\right|<\left|\dfrac{2}{N^2}\right|=\left|\dfrac{2}{2/\epsilon}\right|=\epsilon\text{.}$$

Comment: I hope the edits are as fine as your answer :)

Comment: @Shashi Thank you, that was bothering me!